# Import could not be resolved when trying to create mezzanine project in a venv with vs code

Tags: python, django, pip, python-venv, mezzanine

I tried to setup my first mezzanine project in a venv.
`pip install mezzanine` gives me the warning `django-contrib-comments 2.1.0 has requirement Django>=2.2, but you'll have django 1.11.29 which is incompatible.`.
Why does it want to use django-contrib-comments at all if mezzanine only works with older django versions? When I open the env folder in vs-code I get several
`import could not be resolved` and `foo is not defined`warnings.

I tried to change the interpreter by choosing it in the dropdown-menu, by changing my `settings.json` and by updating the venv path as stated in https://techinscribed.com/python-virtual-environment-in-vscode/ and I checked for the pip and python version.
The strange thing is that I get

```
foundation_site_env python --version
Python 2.7.16
foundation_site_env pip --version
pip 21.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

when I only open the env folder in vs code but

```
(foundation_site_env) ➜  .venv python --version
Python 3.6.8
(foundation_site_env) ➜  .venv pip --version
pip 18.1 from /Users/lindacarmenschmid/.venv/foundation_site_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

when I open the .venv folder in vs code, so it only seems to activate the env when I open the .venv folder, but in both cases the warnings remain the same. Any ideas on what I might have done wrong and what else I can read/try?

Answer (score 0):

`mezzanine` [requires](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/3701d79da81190835f7c25bfb24e623748a28bea/setup.cfg#L36) `django >= 2.2` and `django-contrib-comments >= 1.9`. Looks very much unlike "*mezzanine only works with older django versions*"

Comment: Thank you, that would make sense, I purpously reinstalled an old python-version because in the [documentation overview](https://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/overview.html) they say that it has the depedencies Python 2.7 to 3.6 and
Django 1.8 to 1.11. I'll try it agian with a newer python and django version.